# How to include my custom annotation processor jar file to my other gradle project?

Tags: java, gradle, annotations, annotation-processing

I am writing a simple java application wherein some classes if I annotate with my custom `@Log` annotation should print the message "found @Log annotation at <class_name>". I am trying to experiment with custom annotation processors. For that I wrote a second project which will contain my custom annotation & its processor as follows:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes ("Log")
@AutoService({Processor.class})
public class LogProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public SourceVersion getSupportedSourceVersion() {
        return SourceVersion.latestSupported();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (TypeElement typeElement : annotations) {
            for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(typeElement)) {
                processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, "found @Log annotation at " + element);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And my custom @Log annotation code is as follows:

```
@Target (ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Log {}
```

I am using `@AutoService` for registration of the annotation processor. How do I include the .jar file generated on running a gradle build? I tried the following way:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor name:  'AnnotationSupplier-1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

or

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor files('/libs/AnnotationSupplier-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')
}
```

But that is not working, and I am not sure how else to add a annotation processor jar. My expectation is that upon running the project with my AnnotationSupplier-1.0-SNAPSHOT added, I should be able to see "found @Log annotation at <class_name>" in the console, which I am not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the problem was solved by adding the annotation processor module under the parent project (by creating a new module) and adding the following in the parent `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor project(':AnnotationProcessor')
    compile project(':AnnotationProcessor')
}
```

Note 1: AnnotationProcessor is the name of my annotation processor module which I created under the parent project.

Note 2: I am doing this in IntelliJ IDE.

Note 3: Make sure to activate annotation processing for the project

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as a workaround:

```
implementation files('/path/to/custom-processor.jar')

annotationProcessor files('/path/to/custom-processor.jar')
```

Comment: Nope, on doing that intelliJ can't find `@Log` annotation. It gives following: `package annotations does not exist.
import annotations.Log;`

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: No, even that is not working, still Cannot resolve symbol 'Log'.

Comment: instead of doing `implementation files('/path/to/custom-processor.jar')` if I do `implementation name: 'custom-processor'` then it can detect the annotation. But on running the project, I still don't see the expected result.

Comment: Any resource/example would be helpful.